# I was rotating 4 images around a circle border and stopping one image at 90 degrees and showing its content. I want to increase size of that image

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I was able to rotate 4 images around a circle border and able to stop one image at every 45 degrees. But I cant increase the size of that image which stops at 90 degrees to website and should be able to show the content of respective image when they come at 90 degrees. give me a answer to get out of this using html, css and JavaScript.

**HTML code**

```
 <div id="parent-circle">
        <div class="circle blue">vinay</div>
        <div class="circle pink">vinay</div>
        <div class="circle lime">vinay</div>
        <div class="circle orange">vinay</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5 content  pt-2 ">
        <h1>Health Record</h1>
        <p class="w-75">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, doloremque!</p>
    </div>
```

```
 body {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


body #parent-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border: 0.4vw solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  animation: rotate 14s infinite linear;
}
body #parent-circle .circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: -14%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
body #parent-circle .circle.blue {
  background-color: #416ba9;
  transform: translate(10vw);
    -webkit-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -moz-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -ms-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
}
body #parent-circle .circle.pink {
  background-color: #e6427a;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -moz-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -ms-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
}
body #parent-circle .circle.lime {
  background-color: #cddb00;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -moz-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -ms-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
}
body #parent-circle .circle.orange {
  background-color: #e0592a;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-270deg);
    -webkit-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -moz-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -ms-animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  animation: 25s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
  }
 

  100% {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

**CSS CODE**

[This is the output I was getting. I was able to stop at 90 degrees but cant increase the size of that image and show its respective image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlZ1h.png).

[This is what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1e49.png)

Comment: Please be sure to include all of your code (for example, the `spin_1` keyframes is currently missing from your CSS snippet), and if you could format your example as a working StackSnippet (the `<>` icon in the toolbar), that would helpful as well.

Comment: Spin_1 is not working as expected so didint added.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified way to achieve what you wanted of scaling the circles at 90 degrees while keeping their orientation.

Update!!

You can change the scale from 1.5 to what you want, but make sure to change them all.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


#parent-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0.4vw solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate 7s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: 0;


}

.circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.circle-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  animation-delay: 0;
  background: gray;
}


#blue-circle {
  background: blue;
  animation: circleRotateBlue 7s infinite linear;

}

#pink-circle {
  background: pink;
  animation: circleRotatePink 7s infinite linear;

}

#lime-circle {
  background: lime;
  animation: circleRotateLime 7s infinite linear;

}

#orange-circle {
  background: orange;
  animation: circleRotateOrange 7s infinite linear;

}

.blue {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pink {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.lime {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.orange {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}




.content {
  margin-left: 20%;
}



@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  12.5%,
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)
  }

  37.5%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  62.5%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  }

  87.5%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}




@keyframes circleRotateBlue {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.5);
  }

  12.5%,
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }

  37.5%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }

  62.5%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }

  87.5%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(1.5);
  }
}


@keyframes circleRotateLime {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  12.5%,
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1.5);
  }

  37.5%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }

  62.5%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }

  87.5%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }

}



@keyframes circleRotatePink {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  12.5%,
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }

  37.5%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }

  62.5%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg) scale(1.5);
  }

  87.5%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }

}


@keyframes circleRotateOrange {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  12.5%,
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }

  37.5%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg) scale(1.5);
  }

  62.5%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }

  87.5%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="parent-circle">
  <div class="circle blue">
    <div id="blue-circle" class="circle-content">vinay</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle pink">
    <div id="pink-circle" class="circle-content">vinay</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle lime">
    <div id="lime-circle" class="circle-content">vinay</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle orange">
    <div id="orange-circle" class="circle-content">vinay</div>
  </div>
</div>
```